# Abstract Class vs Interface when using generic type in typescript

Tags: typescript

I am using generic type in typescript to represent the return type of my class' function but using abstract class give me error while interface doesn't.

```
interface IBase<T extends IBaseSecond> {
  baseSecond: T;

  fnA(): ReturnType<T["baseSecondFn"]>;
}

class ImpleIBase implements IBase<ImpleIBaseSecond> {
  baseSecond = new ImpleIBaseSecond();
  fnA() {
    return this.baseSecond.baseSecondFn();
  }
}

interface IBaseSecond {
  baseSecondFn(): { baseSecond: string };
}

class ImpleIBaseSecond implements IBaseSecond {
  baseSecondFn() {
    return { baseSecond: "base second", FurtherSecond: "further second" };
  }
}
```

```
abstract class IBase<T extends IBaseSecond> {
  baseSecond: T;

  fnA(): ReturnType<T["baseSecondFn"]> {
    return this.baseSecond.baseSecondFn(); // Error: Type '{ baseSecond: string; }' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<T["baseSecondFn"]>'.ts(2322)

  }
}

class ImpleIBase implements IBase<ImpleIBaseSecond> {
  baseSecond = new ImpleIBaseSecond();
  fnA() {
    return this.baseSecond.baseSecondFn();
  }
}

abstract class IBaseSecond {
  baseSecondFn() {
    return { baseSecond: "baseSecond" };
  }
}

class ImpleIBaseSecond extends IBaseSecond {
  baseSecondFn() {
    return { baseSecond: "base second", FurtherSecond: "further second" };
  }
}
```

And I am expecting that abstract class should have compile well

Comment: The interface has no method impl on which to error. The class method errors because the compiler cannot reason about generic conditional types (`T` is generic and `ReturnType` is a conditional type)... it's a design limitation of TypeScript (see [this comment on ms/TS#44049](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/44049#issuecomment-839291119) for example). The approach I'd take is just to assert the type because the compiler can't see it, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/NVrvnN). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?